# How to access (read/write) local cookies in a JSON API?

Tags: php, json, http, curl

I created a JSON API using PHP and when I access it directly (by the address bar) it is able to read and write cookies in the local browser.

When I use `cURL` or `file_get_contents` I can't read and write cookies to the local machine so I tried using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
```

This works fine for reading the cookies but I'm not able to set cookies back to the browser.

The cookies I use are very important (authentication) so I need to get them using the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cookie jar and share it between your cURL "calls". Set both `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`  to point to the same file and you do not need to use `CURLOPT_COOKIE`

Comment: Well, how can I use this? What should be the file/path for the cookie file?

Comment: This cookies will be visible in the browser? Is there any issue in multi-browser support?

Comment: any path you like. It is **your** file where CURL writes to/reads from. No, not visible in browser. Browsers use own jars